# А интересно, слова "купить" и "купать" однокоренные?

Tags: однокоренные-слова

- 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В современном языке это не однокоренные слова (Словарь Тихонова). Если же углубиться в этимологию, то выясняется, что слово **купить** заимствовано из германских языков (гот. kaupon "промышлять торговлей" и далее из *kaupjan; из этого же источника др.-прусск. kaupiskan - вин. ж. "торговля"). Германские слова заимствованы из лат. caupo "лавочник, трактирщик".
Что касается слова **купать**, то достоверной этимологии у него нет. Но по значению корня слово* купать *никак не близко слову* купить*. (По Фасмеру)